# How to do quadratic programming in R?

Tags: r, svm, quadratic-programming

I am trying to solve quadratic problem in R. I have this data:

```
x1          x2      y
0.3858  0.4687      1 
0.4871  0.6110     -1
0.9218  0.4103     -1
0.7382  0.8936     -1
0.1763  0.0579      1
0.4057  0.3529      1
0.9355  0.8132     -1
0.2146  0.0099      1
```

And I need to figure out λ1 to λ8. I tried using the routine: `solve.QP(Dmat, dvec, Amat, bvec, meq=0, factorized=FALSE)` from package `quadprog`. I am confused what to input for `dvec`, `bvec`, `Dmat` in my case. I tried following but it doesn't give correct result:

```
Dmat <- matrix(0,8,8)
Amat<-   matrix(c(0.3858,0.4871,0.9218,0.7382,0.1763,0.4057,0.9355,0.2146,0.4687,0.611,0.4103,0.8936,0.0579,0.3529,0.8132,0.0099),8,2)
dvec<-c(1,-1,-1,-1,1,1,-1,1)
solve.QP(Dmat,dvec,Amat)
```

Result is supposed to be λ1 = 65.5261,λ2=65.5261, λ3 to λ8 = 0. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What is the formulation of the quadratic program you're trying to solve?

Answer (score 0):

add
    diag(Dmat) <- 1
to your code.